# Typescript Enforcing object literal is not working as expected

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue creating an object literal that enforces none primitive values.

**When I attempt to map with primitives it works**

```js
interface StringMap {[key:string]: string }

let foo:StringMap = {
    "key_a": "bar",
    "key_b": 12 //works as expected Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
}
```

**But when I create my own object the map structure is not enforced.**

```js
class ChargeGroup{
}

interface ChargeGroupMap { [ key: string ]: ChargeGroup }
type ChargeGroupMap = { [ key: string ]: ChargeGroup } //tried this aswell

let foo:ChargeGroupMap = {
    "key_c": new ChargeGroup()
    "key_a": "bar", //no error
    "key_b": 12, //no error
}
```

**current tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions":{
        "target": "es6",
        "strict": true,
        "watch": true,
        "lib": ["dom", "es2018"],
        "types": [
            "dinero.js",
            "angular"
        ],
        "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "outFile": "../script/invoice.js",
        "noEmitOnError": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Any assistance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an empty class. Typescript uses structural compatibility, so your empty class is equivalent to the `{}`, ie a type with no requirements. This means anything is assignable to it including `number` or `string`. As soon as you add a property to your class you will get errors.

```
class ChargeGroup{
    private notStructural!: unknown
}

interface ChargeGroupMap { [ key: string ]: ChargeGroup }


let foo:ChargeGroupMap = {
    "key_c": new ChargeGroup(),
    "key_a": "bar", //no error
    "key_b": 12, //no error
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAWYBOBzApgcSQewK4AcBvAKGjOnyQEsA3MAFzWgDtt6BlepXYe3JMCACEALmi5mAa1YB3ZsQC+xYlWaMkAMzDAmCZOix58AWTD5ohaAG1oktAE8xELqpTQAumL2pMOAtCVlEDR6aA1sbBFvAz8TM2gAXgtScgAiO3sAfWBUsWY0GThEH0MCAAoASgAaFLJ0h0ywXOhUgCNkVKroAHpu1mg0JBwkWpaMzNbmgEYAJi7e-sHhxSA)

Comment: Note that at least one of the added property must be private or shouldn't exist on primitives types for this to work: only adding a `toString` method  to the `ChargeGroup` class would still allow to add primitive values to your map.

Comment: I was adding methods and constructors to try and get this behavior, funny I didn't even think about adding a property. Thank you